# AFNetworking multi-part mp4 upload Error

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, multipartform-data, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload mp4 video using AFNetworking. It's giving me error

```
file =         (
            "The file must be a file of type: mp3, jpeg, bmp, png, mp4, wmv, avi."
        );
```

Here is the code I am using to upload:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:webURL parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       BOOL isAppended = [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathStr] name:@"file" fileName:@"report.mp4" mimeType:@"video/mp4" error:nil];
        if (isAppended) {
            NSLog(@"appended successfully!");
        }
    } error:nil];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSProgress *progress = nil;

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:&progress completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
        multiPartCallBack(response,responseObject,error);
    }];

    [uploadTask resume];
```